# Java JNA WindowProc JVM Crash

Tags: java, jvm, jna, wndproc

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678247/java-jna-windowproc-implementation) I wanted to implement the `WndProc` to handle the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message in order to know when my USB device is attached or detached.

I managed to solve this issue, but .... in some cases the JVM crashes with the followin ugly error message:

```
    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

      EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1000cb77, pid=3448, tid=4432

     JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
     Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
     Problematic frame:
     C  0x1000cb77

     If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
       http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
     The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
     See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I found that it only crashes the JVM if I close my frame quickly after inserting my USB device, so probably the message isn't handled properly. In the error message it says that there is a "problematic frame", so probably my hidden static window, that handles the WM_DEVICECHANGE message causes the crash, but I'm not sure.

So my question is what can be done in this situation, or what could cause the JVM crash. Any suggestions are welcome.

Regards, Gabor

Answer (score 1):

The problematic frame refers to a stack frame (i.e. a running method). It does *not* refer to a window (`java.awt.Frame` or `javax.swing.JFrame`).

Does closing your window somehow interact with the JNI code?

Comment: I'm not using JNI, only JNA. I can post the code if it would help.

Comment: @Gabor: that doesn't matter, the effects are the same (and JNA uses JNI under the hood as well).

Comment: if JNA uses JNI then probably my window interacts with JNI through JNA, because in the WndProc of my hidden window I handle the WM_DESTROY message to close the handles I use for the USB communication, and then I call the DestroyWindow method, like this: case MyWinUser.WM_DESTROY:{
                    usbComm.CloseHIDDevice();
                    MyUser32.MYINSTANCE.DestroyWindow(usbCommWindow);
                    break;
                }