# How create a global hook usb device with JNA?

Tags: java, usb, hook, jna

I'm trying get WM_DEVICECHANGE notification using Windows hooks based in this example of mouse hook (http://www.javawebdevelop.com/3205624/), but method that contains this constant is never called and when put usb device in my machine I not get any notification. Sincerely I don't know how solve. Any suggestion is welcome!

I'm using NetBeansIDE and Here is my code that I'm trying now:

`package testusbnotification;

public class TESTUSBNOTIFICATION {

    public static void messagem(String s) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
    }

    public static final int WH_GETMESSAGE = 3;
    static HHOOK msgHook;   
    static HOOKPROC msgProc;   

    public interface MyWinUser extends WinUser {
        public static final int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        msgProc = new GetMsgProc() {     
            @Override
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MSG lParam) {
                if (nCode >= 0) {
                    switch(wParam.intValue()) {    
                    case MyWinUser.WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                        messagem("A Usb device was detected!");                           
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(msgHook, nCode, wParam, lParam.getPointer());
            }
        };

        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
        msgHook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, msgProc, hMod, 0);

        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while (User32.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) != 0) {
            User32.INSTANCE.TranslateMessage(msg);
            User32.INSTANCE.DispatchMessage(msg);       
        }

        User32.INSTANCE.UnhookWindowsHookEx(msgHook);
    }

    public static interface GetMsgProc extends HOOKPROC {
        LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MSG lParam);
    }

}`

Comment: Check your win32 requirements for adding a window hook.  If the hook code is required to reside within a DLL, then you cannot use JNA to implement the hook (low-level mouse/keyboard hooks are a special case which do not have this requirement).

Comment: @technomage, Regarding the above code, just monitoring Windows messages by hook, is really possible get WM_DEVICECHANGE?

Comment: Find a working example in native code, then try to duplicate it using Java/JNA.  I don't see anything to indicate why your top-level window (JFrame) would *not* be able to process that message.  Make sure you have an extant JFrame so windows has someplace to send the message.

Comment: @tecnomage, I had asked it, because as you know, each thing in Windows SO have yours specific functions for interception and manipulation of messages, like for `Mouse=>MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT and LowLevelMouseProc`, and for `Keyborad=> KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT and LowLevelKeyboardProc` see these example(http://www.oschina.net/code/piece_full?code=9277) :). But and now; and similar functions for usb device? a simple `MSG lParam` varible as one of parameters into `public LRESULT callback` method? you understood this my logic?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to indicate that you need to perform an additional registration step in order to receive the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` events.

Comment: @technomage, I found a possible solution for my trouble [see](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/native_window_msg/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32WindowDemo.java). I need really of a window for get Windows messages like you said. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678247/java-jna-windowproc-implementation) in this thread also the author found a similar solution for his problem. In your opinion, work this?

Comment: You absolutely need *some* form of window to act as the message destination (otherwise what handle will you use for the WindowProc?).  Win32 may have some special types of hidden windows you can use for this purpose, but to start with just make your own JFrame and get its native window handle.