# Is the WindowProcedure always called in the JavaFX Application Thread?

Tags: java, javafx, callback, jna

In a JavaFX app, if I use the JNA to implement a custom window procedure, will the callback always be on the JavaFX Application Thread?

```
public class MyWindowProc implements WinUser.WindowProc

...

    @Override
    public WinDef.LRESULT callback(WinDef.HWND hwnd, int uMsg, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, WinDef.LPARAM lParam) {
        // Is this guaranteed to always be true?
        System.out.println(Platform.isFxApplicationThread());

    ...
}
```

I assumed it wouldn't, but when I call `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` I always get `true`. Is this guaranteed to always be the case?

Comment: I don't know anything about `WindowProc`, but you can ensure, at least from Java, that code is executed on the JavaFX application thread by invoking [`Platform.runLater`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) if `isFxApplicationThread()` is false, perhaps that is your answer.

Comment: See [this answer to JAVA JNA WindowProc implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28693513/1155209).  I don't know how your callback was registered or used. My guess is that it has been registered on the JavaFX application thread and the calls to translate and dispatch the messages are being invoked in the JavaFX application thread.  That is just speculation on my part.  If that were the case then perhaps all of the calls would occur on the JavaFX application thread.  If it were me and I didn't really know (which I don't), then I'd still call runLater if not on the fx thread.